# Display point values on numbers graph

Tags: numbers

On an Excel graph, if I mouse-over a data point on the graph, the application shows me in a small pop-up window the exact X and Y data values of the point that I am mousing-over.

Is there a way to do this with Numbers.app, either as a mouse-over, or some other way, so I can see the exact data values of a given point on the graph, without having to go back and look at the table that was used to generate the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Select the graph, go to Format, Series tab, then select a Value Label.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a start.  Problem is I have a graph of about 500 x,y points, so when I add the labels they overlap one another quite a bit.  Very hard to read (unless I make the graph so large that only a small portion of it fits on the screen).   For now I've tried instead adding more major grid lines so that I can at least better estimate the value of the points.  Ideally I'd like to be able to mouse-over, or long-press, a particular data point and have it show me that point's value.  Or maybe turn on Value Labels for just every 10th or 20th point?

Comment: You can decrease the size of the value labels by clicking a value, then setting the font size under format > value labels. AFAIK there is no better way.